# Edit text (help pls)

Tags: android, android-edittext

Я новичок. Есть `EditText` , нужно чтобы при вводе определенного слова в этот `EditText` , менялось название кнопки - а если слово не подходит по определенным условиям, то меняться ничего не будет.

Подскажите каким образом осуществить задумку, я совершенно не представляю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить реализацией интерфейса [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Пусть имеется `EditText mEditText` и `Button mButton`, тогда:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().equals("example")) {
                mButton.setText("Button text");
            }
        }
    });
```

В методе `afterTextChanged(...)` Вы проверяете введенное слово `s.toString()`, если оно является словом `example`, то кнопке `mButton` назначается заголовок `Button text`.

Comment: А можно ли сделать так , чтобы если введенное слово было example, то при нажатии на другую кнопку ( проверка ) , было также какое - нибудь событие.

Comment: Можно. Для этого при нажатии на кнопку нужно проверять `mEditText.getText().toString()`.